# How to avoid migrations in model first database with Entity Framework 5 and code first entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I started an ASP.NET MVC 4 project with an existing database and for map the existing models I created a ADO.NET Entity Data Model called Legacy.edmx.
For my new entities, I'm using code first in meaning to use migrations and in-model validations. Some entities have foreign keys from auto generated entities from ADO.

The problem is, if I try to generate migrations it tries to create all the tables again from Legacy.edmx.

How to avoid this behavior? Or, theres another approach for make this scenario work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: `Add-Migration -IgnoreChanges`